# permission denied error while reading an excel file

Tags: python, error-handling

i got a permission denied error while i tried to open an excel file.

I dont have the ms excel complete version. I mean, im just using the trial version. 
Could it be because of that?

my code has just 4 lines

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_excel("E:\\ML")
```

Comment: no it has nothing to do with what type of MS Excel you have.

Comment: what is your excel file name? in your code you have given only a path. you need to provide the name of your excel file.

Comment: "permission denied error" is usually because the file is already opened by someone. See if anyone with access to the file (including you) might be using it, or if you run another code that might still be holding this file open.

Answer (score 0):

It's something about how file open function works. I successfully reproduced your problem and find the way.

It's believed that you have a directory named `ML` in `E` disk, and maybe there are some excels files (such as `*.xls` or `*.xlsx`) in `ML`(I bet you just started learning machine learning). Now you try to load the excel data into your program, but you give the path `E:\\ML`, which is a directory instead of a file, so operation is forbidden by system when pandas try to serialize the directory as a file, which is the cause of error "Permission denied".

The method is that you're supposed to use file path like `E:\\ML\\your_database_file_name.xls`.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Please try to re-write your answer without unnecessary remarks that may offend (such as "you don't understand", "you just started learning"). We are here to help and support, not to criticize and diminish.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turns out that it was because I had the same Excel file opened (I kept getting the error while trying to push my work to Github) which was resolved immediately after I closed the MS Excel (the program using the file I wanted to push..)
I hope you find this helpful!